# setup.py imports not working correctly

Tags: python, import, setup.py

I'm trying to install a simple python library I created and think I may be missing a step. The setup goes fine (or runs at least) but when I import it doesn't work as I expect.
The directory structure looks like

```
Foo/
  setup.py
  README.txt
  LICENSE.txt
    foo/
      __init__.py
      bar.py
```

I can do

```
>>> import foo
```

but then if I try to

```
>>> foo.bar
```

I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

Contrarily no errors occur if I use

```
>>> from foo import bar
```

Here is my setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='Foo',
    version='0.1.0',
    author='ctrl-c',
    author_email='10minutemail@10minutemail.com',
    packages=['foo'],
    license='LICENSE.txt',
    description='Foo does bar.',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
)
```

I imagine I just missed something, but I've been looking through the docs and haven't found it yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup.py appears fine. How are you installing your package?  For example:

```
% cd Foo
% python setup.py install --root /tmp/fooroot
% PYTHONPATH=/tmp/fooroot python -c 'from foo import bar; print bar'
<module 'foo.bar' from 'foo/bar.py'>
```

If you're on an RPM-based system you can create an installable RPM using this:

```
% python setup.py bdist_rpm
% sudo rpm -i dist/Foo-0.1.0-1.noarch.rpm
# now should be available to python globally
```

If you want the `bar` symbol to be visible as an attribute on `foo` by default, do this:

In `foo/__init__.py`:

```
import bar
```

Comment: adding import foo to __init__.py was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: This must be something that is fairly common practice for most packages, i.e. I can `import numpy` and get at `numpy.linalg` without problems.

Comment: You're right. Many package authors choose to export commonly-used symbols from the package itself. It is best to implement these as modules and expose them via `__init__.py`, i.e. don't implement classes/functions directly in `__init__.py`, just use it to control which symbols are part of the package namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Your `foo` is a package, and packages don't automatically import modules. You have to do explicitly. That's just how Python works.  You can also do `import foo.bar` and reference `foo.bar` then.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do such a thing, you have to fill the foo/__init__.py with :

```
import bar
```

and then, when importing foo, you will be able to use foo.bar

Otherwise, use the

```
import foo.bar
```